# Run script Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scripting

I have a set of commands that I run in the bin/rails console, for example:

```
AppConfig.settings.captcha.enable = false
success = user.sign_up
etc ...
```

Can I make a script like bin/bash to execute all commands at once? (I would like it to be a executable file, since I want to change the input data in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the commands into a file (script), add the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`), make the file executable and run it from the command line like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# require ... (load the libraries here)
...
AppConfig.settings.captcha.enable = false
success = user.sign_up
#etc ...
```

```
# Make executable
chmod u+x my_script.rb

# Run the script
/path/to/my_script.rb
```

Comment: If I need to enter: "bin/rails console development" to start the shell, then enter this path in "require"?

Comment: No, just `require` the libraries you are using (for example, `require pg`, `require active_record`, etc). The command you mention, [`bin/rails console`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-console), lets you interact with your Rails application from the command line. It is not a library that you need to load in your ruby script.

Comment: What does the code look like if I first need to go to "bin / rails console"?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misunderstood your question. I thought you already *had* your code (which you posted) that you ran successfully in `bin/rails console` . If that's incorrect, I did not answer your question. It may be worth posting this as another, different, question, perhaps with some additional clarification.